# create express app after cloning from github

Tags: node.js, express, github

How to create (generate) an express app inside a folder which was cloned from github? Something similar to `npm init`.

Example:

- Create a **new** repo on github called: express-app.
- Clone it to local machine.
- Go inside express-app folder.
- Then generate an express app folder structure inside express-app?

I know I can use `express-generator` to create a new repo first (`express express-app`), then push it to github later, but how about the opposite way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just generate it inside the cloned empty folder this way.

```
express .
```

dot being the current directory

Comment: thank you @Ayaz Hussein. it works if i install express-generator with npm, but not with yarn. i've reported the bug to the yarn team.

Answer (score 0):

The github repo that you clone to your local machine is just that - a github repo, albeit empty in your scenario. The only difference (at least from the information provided) is that you are doing `git init` in a different place.

In general, you should use the same command you use for generating the app on a folder w/o cloning from github.